# I want to change .jpg or .png to .jpg:orig or .png:orig with greasemonkey

Tags: javascript

I want to change .jpg or .png to .jpg:orig or .png:orig with greasemonkey
ex.https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DMU-nlSV4AAom3a.jpg to https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DMU-nlSV4AAom3a.jpg:orig

```
// ==UserScript== 
// @name        Twitter Orig jpg
// @namespace   jirat
// @include     https://pbs.twimg.com/*
// @include     https://pbs.twimg.com/media/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
document.location.replace(document.location.href.replace(/.jpg/,'.jpg:orig'));
```

but when it run, it won't stop. It keep going repleace like this

```
[.jpg:orig:orig:orig:orig]
```

How can I fix this.

Comment: Check if your url already contains `:orig` before setting it?

Comment: looks like replace() working multiple times. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1144783/4229270

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the `:orig` already exists

```
let href = document.location.href;

if(href.includes('.jpg') && !href.includes(':orig')){
  document.location.href = href.replace(/.jpg/,'.jpg:orig');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `/\.jpg$/` for the regex to match only at the end of the url.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the location URL for .jpg or .png

```
function setLocationUrl(){
  let href = document.location.href;
  if(href.lastIndexOf(':orig') == -1 && (href.lastIndexOf('.jpg') || href.lastIndexOf('.png'))){
  let location = href.replace(/.jpg/,'.jpg:orig');
  document.location = location;
  }
}

setLocationUrl();
```